# django notification system for single user

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I would like to create a notification system
I created the badge that signals me the notification on its page to see the various notifications and through ajax with the GET method I update the number of notifications.
Not being attached to a single user, the count remains the number of notifications and I would like that user who clicks the 'read' button the notification is no longer seen and the conuter decreases.
But how do I do it for the single user, I can do it but it would work for each user and not for the single one and that's it.

model

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255) 
    text = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

View notification + view ajax notification

```
def notifiche(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        notifica = request.POST['id_notifica']
        oggetto = get_object_or_404(Notification, id = notifica)
        if oggetto.active == True:
            oggetto.active = False
            messaggio = "Notifica disattivata"
        else:
            oggetto.active = True
            messaggio = "Notifica attiva sul sito"
            
        oggetto.save()
        return JsonResponse({'oggetto': oggetto.active, 'messaggio': messaggio}, status=200)
    else:
        notifiche = Notification.objects.all()
        context = {'notifiche':notifiche, 'popup':popup}
        return render(request, 'notifiche.html', context)


def popup(request):
    popup = Notification.objects.filter(active = True).count()

    return JsonResponse({'popup': popup}, status=200)
```

Snippets/nav.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" aria-current="page" href="{% url 'notifiche' %}">
                        Notifiche <span class="badge bg-danger">0</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Ajax code in base.html

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/notifiche/",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $("nav span.badge").text(response.popup);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by many ways :

- If every users receiving the notification have an account name registered, add a users field with checkbox or TextField with a split("\n")
- You can also use cookies or data stored locally and don't display the notification if already shown once (can be done 100% in js and without an account system)

Probably more ways...

Comment: do you have any resource to link to me to get an idea of how to do it,
the first one you told me could be for me but I didn't understand what you mean, the second could be simple but I'm not very familiar with cookies so I don't know how to move and so if you have any resources to link to me you would do me a great favor.